# how to fill datatable from details view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable, detailsview

I have a work order management application, I was requested to add a new functionality, they wanted a way to attach docs,pdf's,images,etc

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attach">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="True" />
        <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload_Click" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[image]

I used a fileupload

Now I want the attachment to be inserted in the database only when the user clicks submit, so I was thinking if there is a way to insert the attachment from the details view into a data table when user clicks upload button, so then I can bind that data table to the gridview and when the user clicks submit I want it to get inserted into the database??

my code behind

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    FileUpload file1 = (FileUpload)DetailsView1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in file1.PostedFiles)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

        using (Stream fs = postedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WorkOrderConnectionString3"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    DataTable table = CreateDatatable();
                    table.Rows.Add()
                    string query = "insert into tblFiles values (@Name, @Data)";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);                                
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

as you can see above instead of insert into table, I want to insert into `datatable` `detailsview.findcontrol("fileupload1")` values.

any suggestions will be strongly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    FileUpload file1 = (FileUpload)DetailsView1.FindControl("FileUpload1");

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Bytes", typeof(byte[]));

    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in file1.PostedFiles)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

        using (Stream fs = postedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                table.Rows.Add(fileName, bytes);
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Comment: Hey bud you answer worked only thing I had to change the filename to filename when you add it to the table rows but now how would I call the datatable rows when the submit button is clicked??

Comment: You can declare your `DataTable` inside your class, to have access from all over it. Or create a `DataTable` property: `public DataTable Table { get; set; }` then assign value to it inside your event handler.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of observations:

Do not use a relational database to store files. Think of it as this: if you will never be filtering/querying for a value in a column, then that column is just costing you money. Store the files on disk, and keep a reference to the filename and path in a NoSql table. It's cheaper, faster, and less complex to handle.

You can easilly post the file to storage, and have a submission table with contains the file name, it's path, and an expiration date/time that you calculate, i.e. 24hours. A nightly process can just delete all expired files from the submission table, and when your user clicks on submit, the file is added to a different table (but still NoSQL, don't ever use relational databases for files!) with only the file name, path and other vital info being shifted.

Comment: Why not? MY answer tells the OP to create a submission table with an expiration date on the submission - very common solution to the scenario he is describing. Storing files in ER databases is plain wrong, and should not be encouraged in any way.